# An efficient way to store and load parameters in an iteratively called function

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management

I've been working on a problem where I need to simulate a system. I've stripped the relevant code I've written to only the parts important to this question.

```
def oscillatorParams():
    K1,K2,K3 = 1e5,1e6,1e2
    B1,B2,B3 = 100,100,100
    a1,a2,a3 = 1,1,1
    b1,b2,b3 = 1,1,1
    I1,I2,I3 = 1000,10000,20000
    return K1,K2,K3,B1,B2,B3,a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,I1,I2,I3

def ode_3DOF_oscillator(state,t, u):
    K1, K2, K3, B1, B2, B3, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, I1, I2, I3 = oscillatorParams()
    ..equations for the odesolver..
    return [omega[0],omega[1],omega[2],dw1dt,dw2dt,dw3dt]

def runSim(u,dt,T):
    t=np.arange(0,T,dt) ; N=len(t)
    for i in range(0, N ):
        if i==N-1 or i==N:
            tt = [t[i], t[i]]  # [t1 t2]
        else:
            tt = [t[i], t[i+1]]  # [t1 t2]
        x=odeint(ode_3DOF_oscillator,x0,tt,args=(M[i,:],))
    return t,y1,y2,y3
```

I don't have a strong programming background and I'm confused as how to *optimally* implement the parameters. I'd prefer to store the parameters somewhere to make them easily editable as I'll probably be using these functions in multiple other files, but I assume this function will keep allocating the parameters with every ode_3DOF_oscillator(state,t,u) call. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: That should not be a problem at all. Do you have evidence that this piece of code is giving troubles?

Comment: No, I don't think it would be noticeable in this case, since it's just 15 values. I am just trying to learn good practices along the way and, if I understand this correctly, if I had, say, 1000 floats I'd have to load in every iteration, it might become more recognizable.
But overall, I was just looking for a feedback for my code from someone more experienced and perhaps see what the best practice is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to explain your existing code, every iteration of the ODE solver Python has to:

1. invoke `ode_3DOF_oscillator` which immediately invokes `oscillatorParams`
2. local variables get set to your parameter variables
3. local variables get turned into a tuple and function returns
4. the returned tuple get unpacked into a set of local variables for use later
5. the rest of your code runs until it returns a result

assuming you're happy hardcoding parameter values in the source code, I'd either do something like:

```
def make_3DOF_oscillator():
    K1,K2,K3 = 1e5,1e6,1e2
    B1,B2,B3 = 100,100,100
    a1,a2,a3 = 1,1,1
    b1,b2,b3 = 1,1,1
    I1,I2,I3 = 1000,10000,20000

    def fn(state, t, u):
        # ..equations for the odesolver..
        return [omega[0],omega[1],omega[2],dw1dt,dw2dt,dw3dt]

    return fn

def runSim(u,dt,T):
    myfn = make_3DOF_oscillator()
    t=np.arange(0,T,dt) ; N=len(t)
    for i in range(0, N ):
        if i==N-1 or i==N:
            tt = [t[i], t[i]]  # [t1 t2]
        else:
            tt = [t[i], t[i+1]]  # [t1 t2]
        x=odeint(myfn, x0,tt,args=(M[i,:],))
    return t,y1,y2,y3
```

this leads to good performance as the parameters are directly available in the function `fn` as local variables (as opposed to global ones which are slightly slower).  also the parameters are only set once rather than every step.

otherwise, assuming performance isn't a concern and you don't mind slightly more typing, you could use classes:

```
class Oscillator3DOF:
    def __init__(self):
        self.K1, self.K2, self.K3 = 1e5,1e6,1e2
        self.B1, self.B2, self.B3 = 100,100,100
        self.a1, self.a2, self.a3 = 1,1,1
        self.b1, self.b2, self.b3 = 1,1,1
        self.I1, self.I2, self.I3 = 1000,10000,20000

    def deriv(self, y, t, u):
        # ..equations for the odesolver..
        return [omega[0],omega[1],omega[2],dw1dt,dw2dt,dw3dt]

def runSim(u,dt,T):
    system = Oscillator3DOF()
    t=np.arange(0,T,dt) ; N=len(t)
    for i in range(0, N ):
        if i==N-1 or i==N:
            tt = [t[i], t[i]]  # [t1 t2]
        else:
            tt = [t[i], t[i+1]]  # [t1 t2]
        x=odeint(system.deriv, x0,tt,args=(M[i,:],))
    return t,y1,y2,y3
```

note that `deriv` would access parameters as `self.K1` etc.

another option would be to use something like [`namedtuple`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to store your parameters once.  this would make it easier to save the parameter values outside the source code, which can be a desirable property

not quite sure what your `M` and `u` parameters are for, but I'd be tempted to set them up in the same way.  e.g. pass them to `make_3DOF_oscillator(M[i,:])` which makes it available within `fn`, or to save it as a member variable in the constructor of `Oscillator3DOF`.  in these cases you'd want to create the objects within the `for i` loop so it gets access to the right thing